# installing postgres on ubuntu package not available

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I'm setting up a VPS with Ruby and Postgres. On my local machine, I have postgresql 9.2.3 (client and server) installed and therefore wanted to install the same on my VPS. Following the instructions of this blog post http://hendrelouw73.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/how-to-install-postgresql-9-1-on-ubuntu-12-10-linux/for installing postgres on ubuntu (with the only difference that I'm trying to install 9.2.3. and he installed 9.1), I did the following

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-9.2.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.2.3'
```

However, as you can see, it couldn't find a package `postgresql-9.2.3`. Yet, I have that package installed on my local machine (which I installed on my Mac with Homebrew).

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Update
I also tried to install it leaving off the '3' at the end like you see below but it didn't work as you can see.

```
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-9.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-9.2' has no installation candidate
```

Update

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages [259 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages [192 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 501 kB in 3s (148 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
postgresql-9.1 - object-relational SQL database, version 9.1 server
postgresql-9.1-dbg - debug symbols for postgresql-9.1
postgresql-9.1-debversion - Debian version number type for PostgreSQL
postgresql-9.1-ip4r - IPv4 and IPv4 range index types for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-orafce - Oracle support functions for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-pgfincore - set of PostgreSQL functions to manage blocks in memory
postgresql-9.1-pgmemcache - PostgreSQL interface to memcached
postgresql-9.1-pgmp - arbitrary precision integers and rationals for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-pgpool2 - connection pool server and replication proxy for PostgreSQL - modules
postgresql-9.1-pljava-gcj - Java procedural language for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-pllua - Lua procedural language for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-plproxy - database partitioning system for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-plr - Procedural language interface between PostgreSQL and R
postgresql-9.1-plsh - PL/sh procedural language for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-postgis - Geographic objects support for PostgreSQL 9.1
postgresql-9.1-prefix - Prefix Range module for PostgreSQL
postgresql-9.1-preprepare - Pre Prepare your Statement server side
postgresql-9.1-slony1-2 - replication system for PostgreSQL: PostgreSQL 9.1 server plug-in
```

Comment: what does `apt-get update && apt-cache search ^postgresql-9` output?

Comment: @dawud posted the contents of running that in the update to the OP.

Comment: so how do you expect to install a package that is not available?

Comment: @dawud I didn't consider the possibility that it wouldn't be available since I installed 9.2.3 on my local machine (using Homebrew). This is my first time setting up a VPS.  Why wouldn't it be available?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Ubuntu official repositories only PostgreSQL 9.1 is available. That is why it couldn't be found.

In order to get PostgreSQL v9.2 in your VPS using apt you should follow the official PostgreSQL procedure for Ubuntu found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

It consists of adding PostgreSQL official repository as one of your repository source

1. Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`
2. Insert this line `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main`
3. Import the repository signing key `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
4. Refresh your repositories cache `sudo apt-get update`

Now you can simply do `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2`

Comment: Didn't know there was a repo for this. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. See, even my downvoted question helped experienced users ....

Comment: I found this page very helpful http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt.  You can also install postgres-contrib-9.2

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you were able to install `postgresql-9.2.3` on a **different operating system** using **different repositories** is not relevant.

If you query the [Ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/database/postgresql) using the web or through `apt`, you will notice that the version shipped with quantal is 9.1.

The exact reason why `postgresql-9.2.3` is not available in quantal is because it was not accepted in the released distribution by the time it was frozen.

To use `postgresql-9.2.3` in Ubuntu, you need to compile it yourself. There are several approaches to this, like backporting or packaging an upstream release with checkinstall or fpm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm sort of a newbie about to manage a professional server :(